# Trigger a funtion when a check box is true - google sheet script

Tags: google-apps-script

[image]I am trying to trigger a function if the (D1) checkbox is true

Instead of a button, I need a checkbox. Button click works only on desktop but not on Mobile/Tablet.

I tried referring to this similar post. But still the script is not running
[Calling function when checking checkbox - Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61536404/calling-function-when-checking-checkbox-google-sheets)

**this code is not working for me. Please guide.**

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange()
  if (range.isChecked()) {
    if (range.getA1Notation() == "D1") {
      searchData()
    } else if (range.getA1Notation() == "E1") {
      submitData()
    }
    range.uncheck()
  }
}
```

for your reference, below is the function I am trying to trigger/call

```
**// Please run this function if the D1 is true.**
function searchdata() {
  const srcSpreadsheetId = "1QL0jaNts2YRkZTlxmS0bk7V1fVVHBsJFmxS5C05PEmA"; 
  const srcSheetName = "DataSheet";
  const dstSheetName = "UserForm";

  // Retrieve values from source sheet and create an array and search value.
  const dstSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const dstSheet = dstSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(dstSheetName);
  const search = dstSheet.getRange("B1").getValue();

  // Search the value.
  const srcSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(srcSpreadsheetId);
  const srcSheet = srcSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(srcSheetName);
  const range = srcSheet.getRange("A2:A" + srcSheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(search).findNext();
  if (!range) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('UserForm Number Not Found');
  }
```

also, this is the working file link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NY_ckzEWxU7DCGro5tTqzpiOi6iG5PAQFxpZg0OKodY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Provide debugging details. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041/how-can-i-test-a-trigger-function-in-gas

Comment: attached screen shot of debugging details

Comment: Did you read my answer there? I already told you how to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Your sheet name" && e.range.rowStart == 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    if(e.range.columnStart == 4) {
      searchData();
    }
    if(e.range.columnStart == 5) {
      submitData();
    }
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
  }
}
```

This works for me

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.rowStart == 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    if(e.range.columnStart == 4) {
      e.source.toast("D1")
      //searchData();
    }
    if(e.range.columnStart == 5) {
      e.source.toast("E1")
      //submitData();
    }
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
  }
}

function createInstallableTrigger(funcname="onMyEdit") {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == funcname).length == 0 ) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger().forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onEdit().create();
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried the given code (added sheet name), but the script is not running (searchData)

Comment: Do I need to change any settings!

Comment: Sheet name, checkboxes in D1 and E1 with values of "TRUE" and "FALSE"

Comment: Yes!  Sheet name is given, inserted checkboxes in D1 and E1, checked; still script not running

Comment: Do you have an e in the function definition?

Comment: I am getting a toast D1 and E1 but SearchData function is not running. :(

Comment: You mean onEdit(e) - YES

Comment: Search  data not running is not very helpful.  Are getting an error? Are getting the alert?

Comment: SearchData function is running with a button click. But I am trying the same function using CheckBox (because I can use it to search data from mobile/tablet).
While using the code provided by you I am not getting any error or alert. Nothing happens. Please help, attached the working sheet link too

Comment: It could by that you need an installable onEdit(e) because GmailApp requires permissions

Comment: Please Can you explain in more detail?. What changes should do in the script or should I enable some settings?

Comment: You don't need to change the script.  Just change the name and create an installable trigger onEdit trigger

Comment: See last part of my answer.

Comment: Sorry!  :(  still nothing happening. > I changed the Sheet name and added the given installable trigger function.  The script is not running. But still button click runs the script.  Is there any alternate method of calling the function using mobile

Comment: I can't help you without more debugging information

Comment: added debugging information - Screenshots for your reference

Comment: Personally, I would have preferred having you try to figure out why searchdata is not running.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246378/discussion-between-humming-bird-and-cooper).

Comment: You haven't created an installable trigger in your code example

Comment: Yes, Now its after creating an installable trigger. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (activeSheet.getName() != "UserForm") return;
  if (range.isChecked()) {
    if (range.getA1Notation() == "D1") {
      searchData();
    } else if (range.getA1Notation() == "E1") {
      submitData();
    }
    range.uncheck();
  }
}
```

When using the `onEdit()` function, make sure to take advantage of the on edit [`event object (e)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) as it can save you from potential bugs.

You might also want to reduce the amount of nested if statements by using this code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (activeSheet.getName() != "UserForm") return;
  if (!range.isChecked()) return;
  if (range.getA1Notation() == "D1") {
    searchData();
  } else if (range.getA1Notation() == "E1") {
    submitData();
  }
  
  range.uncheck();
}
```

Comment: Tried the given code, but the script is not running (searchData)